# Для чего нужен деплой?

Tags: java, maven, развертывание

Для каких сценариев работы требуется команда **mvn deploy**? Спрашиваю, потому что изучаю maven и не знаю, для чего нужен деплой.

Comment: для установки, настройки и запуска приложения в указанной рабочей среде.

Comment: @vi0 deploy: помещает созданный архив в удаленный
репозиторий.

Рекомендую [книгу](https://library.samdu.uz/files/ed0fe9d30649839bc45f7538f21baa2b_Introducing%20Maven.pdf) к прочтению.

Answer (score 2):

deploy копирует окончательный пакет в удаленный репозиторий для совместного использования с другими разработчиками и проектами.